# chef: how do I reboot a node only if a confg file is modified

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, chef

ENVIRONMENT: aws opsworks chef 11.10 and ubuntu 14.04.

I'm using a chef recipe to update the `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file on an aws opsworks ec2 node in order to add my custom dns search suffix to the search line in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

**How do I get my recipe to reboot the node ONLY if the `file.insert_line_if_no_match` updates the file?**  I obviously don't want the node rebooted every time the recipe is run.

In my code snippet below the value of `node['opsworks']['stack']['name']` is something like `a.dev.mydomain.com`.

```
ruby_block "add custom dns domain search suffix" do
  block do
    file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf")
    file.insert_line_if_no_match("/append domain-search/", "append domain-search \"#{node['opsworks']['stack']['name']}\";")
    file.write_file
  end
end
```

The code snippet above adds the last line to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

```
# Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient, which is included in Debian's
#       dhcp3-client package.
#
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;
send host-name = gethostname();
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
        dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
append domain-search "a.dev.mydomain.com";
```

After a reboot, the `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` is modified as follows:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 172.16.0.23
search ec2.internal a.dev.mydomain.com
```

NOTE: I think it is too risky, to try to implement the setting with something like a `sudo dhclient -r; sudo dhclient` after the file update, but I'd love to hear if anyone has gotten this type of update to work without a reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you find a way to do this without restarting the machine.  I did something similar on Centos, for example, which was accomplished with a `sudo service network restart`.  Nonetheless, whether you restart the machine or just a single service, you'll use the same pattern.

## The "right" way

The right way to do this is with a custom resource/provider.  In this case (and there may very well already be one in the community), you would write an LWRP that reads the `dhclient.conf` file and only modifies it if a change is needed.  It would then set `updated_by_last_action` if the file is updated.  At that point you could use a `service` or `execute` resource to restart the service/machine.  The restart resource would subscribe to changes to the LWRP resource.

## The almost as cool way

Or, you do something like this:

```
execute "add custom dns domain search suffix" do
  command "echo 'append domain-search \"#{node['opsworks']['stack']['name']}\";' >> /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf"
  not_if { ::File.open('/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf').read() =~ /append domain-search/ }
end

execute 'restart machine' do
  command 'shutdown immediate -r'
  action :nothing
  subscribes :run, 'execute[add custom dns domain search suffix]'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks Tejay Cardon, your code works like a charm (I promise I'll look into writing a LWRP someday)!

FTR the following code works for me on an aws ec2 ubuntu 14.04 build **without a reboot**.  I was even able to do a `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0` from an ssh session and didn't get disconnected.

```
execute "add custom dns domain search suffix" do
  command "echo 'append domain-search \"#{node['opsworks']['stack']['name']}\";' >> /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf"
  not_if { ::File.open('/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf').read() =~ /append domain-search/ }
end

execute 'bounce eth0' do
  command 'sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0'
  action :nothing
  subscribes :run, 'execute[add custom dns domain search suffix]'
end
```

[For some reason](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441619/how-to-successfully-restart-a-network-without-reboot-over-ssh) `sudo service networking restart` and `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` no longer work post ubuntu 13.04 and I am not doing this on a desktop or `sudo service network-manager restart` may have worked.